# Angular 6 Project failed to load resource Error 421 on Iphone Safari 12

Tags: iphone, angular, build, mobile-safari, http-status-code-421

after building the angular project with

```
ng build --prod
```

all images and files are not loaded in **Safari on Iphone 12**. In Chrome, Safari Desktop and Firefox it works without problems. The error is:

> message: "Http failure response for
> https://myurl.com/assets/i18n/de.json: 421 OK"
>
> 421 Misdirected Request

Build width: Angular CLI: 6.0.8
in Angular: 6.0.5

Thanks!